# in C++, how should I enforce the order of composited object constructors in an initializer list when they have dependencies

Tags: c++, constructor, ctor-initializer

If I have a class that composit other objects that have inter-dependencies, (how) should I enforce their construction order?

E.g.

```
class Parent
{
    Child1 c1;
    Child2 c2;
};
```

Imagine the constructor of Child2 requires a Child1& and I want to pass in c1 to the c2 constructors.

If I just do the following...

```
Parent::Parent()
    : c2(c1)
{
}
```

...this may not be good thing as c1 may not be constructed by the time the initializer for c2 is run? Or is it good enough that c1 comes before c2 in the class declaration?

Or should I explicitly refer the c1 constructor (if that is not neccessary, then is it a good practice to do so to make it explicit?). E.g.

```
class Parent
{
    Child1 c1;
    Child2 c2;
};

Parent::Parent()
    : c1()
    : c2(c1)
{
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Members are always constructed in the order that they are declared. So if you have:

```
class Parent
{
    Child1 c1;
    Child2 c2;
};
```

you are guaranteed that `c1` will be constructed before `c2`. So, if `c2` needs a `Child1&`, then this is perfectly well-defined:

```
Parent::Parent()
    : c2(c1)
{
}
```

`c1` will be default-constructed, and then `c2` will be constructed with a definitely-already-constructed `c1`.

Answer (score 1):

All of this has no effect. The member variables are constructed in the order of their declaration. Full stop.

Here's a full explanation from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list):

> The order of member initializers in the list is irrelevant: the actual order of initialization is as follows:
>
> 1. List item
>      If the constructor is for the most-derived class, virtual base classes are initialized in the order in which they appear in depth-first left-to-right traversal of the base class declarations (left-to-right refers to the appearance in base-specifier lists)
> 2. Then, direct base classes are initialized in left-to-right order as they appear in this class's base-specifier list
> 3. Then, non-static data members are initialized in order of declaration in the class definition.
> 4. Finally, the body of the constructor is executed

Answer (score 1):

The order of declaration in the class is the only relevant thing. Order of construction in the initializer list is not obeyed by the compiler, indeed you can enable a warning that warns you about this fact (order in initializer list != order of effective construction).

Answer (score 1):

In c++ the members in an initializer list are not initialized in the order you put them in the list but in the order you declared them. In fact g++ would output a warning if you don't initialize members in the order you declared them. Thus you should take care to **declare** the members in their logical order - from lower level to higher level object.

Answer (score 1):

Member data is constructed in order of declaration. If `c1` is declared before `c2` (as it is in your examples), then it will be constructed first.

There is a slight difference between your two examples, however:

```
Parent::Parent()
    // c1 is implicitly default-initialized
    : c2(c1)
{
}

Parent::Parent()
    : c1(), //c1 is value-initialized
      c2(c1)
{
}
```

If `Child1` is a non-POD class type, the two are equivalent, but otherwise you'll get an indeterminate value for `c1`.

If this is important to you, you can read about the difference between [default-](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization) and [value-initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization).